# How to append radio buttons in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, laravel-6

Trying to append radio buttons but displays [object Object]. What could be the problem in my code?

```
.append('<li>'+JSON.parse(data.responseText).question+' ('+JSON.parse(data.responseText).score+'pts)
```

'+$.each(JSON.parse(data.responseText).choices, function(key, value){
 {{Form::radio("radio", "value", ["class" => "form-control"])}}'
                    })+'   ');

**Console**

```
choices: Array(4)
0: {id: 121, quiz_question_id: 91, choice: "B", created_at: "2019-11-21 
05:35:42", updated_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42"}
1: {id: 122, quiz_question_id: 91, choice: "G", created_at: "2019-11-21 
05:35:42", updated_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42"}
2: {id: 123, quiz_question_id: 91, choice: "C", created_at: "2019-11-21 
05:35:42", updated_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42"}
3: {id: 124, quiz_question_id: 91, choice: "C1", created_at: "2019-11-21 
05:35:42", updated_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42"}
length: 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.each will not return the text. You will have to append the text within the callback. Please refer to the below sample:

```
     HTML: 
    <label for="search_field">Address</label>
    <input type='text' class='address_field' />
    <li class="some_class"></li>

    Javascript:

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var arr = [1,2,3];
        $.each(arr, function(key,val) {
            $('.some_class').append("(" + val + " )<li>sample1</li>");
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you do a console.log(data.responseText); and send us response here? it seems like question is an object and not an attribute.

Comment: I see that you are iterating over choices. Is this an array of string?

Comment: choices: Array(4)
0: {id: 121, quiz_question_id: 91, choice: "B", created_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42", updated_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42"}
1: {id: 122, quiz_question_id: 91, choice: "G", created_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42", updated_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42"}
2: {id: 123, quiz_question_id: 91, choice: "C", created_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42", updated_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42"}
3: {id: 124, quiz_question_id: 91, choice: "C1", created_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42", updated_at: "2019-11-21 05:35:42"}
length: 4

Comment: This is the problem. As choices is an array of objects, you have to stringify before you print the value. The callback function(key, value) that you have written itetrates over the choices array. So it gets object one by one and these have to be stringified before you can put it in the markup.

Comment: @ArunSelin in my each function, it is looping over the data. but the one it is displaying is the input type="radio" not values in JSON

Comment: Can you also give samples for JSON.parse(data.responseText).question and JSON.parse(data.responseText).score ?

Comment: I am a sample question? (1pts)
undefined

Comment: @ArunSelin the question followed by score and then the undefined because I change the JSON.parse to JSON.stringify in jQUery.each()

Comment: @ArunSelin i tried what you said here it is: A (1pts)
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @Mark-LuigiBatoctoy This is happening because $.each will not return the text as you are expecting. The correct way to do this would be to $.each(choices, function(key, val){ $('li').append("<<insert the radio button code>>")});

Comment: @Mark-LuigiBatoctoy Updated my answer with a sample. Let me know if that helps?

Comment: .append('<li>'+JSON.parse(data.responseText).question+' ('+JSON.parse(data.responseText).score+'pts) <div class="row mb-2"> <div class="col-10"> <div class="form-group">'+$.each(JSON.parse(data.responseText).choices, function(key, value){
                             $(this).closest('form-group').append('{{Form::radio("radio", "value", ["class" => "form-control"])}}');
                    })+' </div> </div> </div></li>');

Comment: still the same, the output is object Object

Comment: $.each part should not be appended to the string using +. This should be put in a separate instruction. Refer to the example that i put in my answer. .append('<li>'+JSON.parse(data.responseText).question+' ('+JSON.parse(data.responseText).score+'pts) <div class="row mb-2"> <div class="col-10"> <div class="form-group"></div> </div> </div></li>'); $.each(JSON.parse(data.responseText).choices, function(key, value){ $(this).closest('form-group').append('{{Form::radio("radio", "value", ["class" => "form-control"])}}'); })